# copy all the package and dependecies from one pc to other pc

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I have Downloaded and installed all the dependencies and .deb packages required to run my software( Custom made GUI software). Now while On the other system I have Installed the same ubuntu version, but it's not connected to Internet. So I have externally downloaded and tried to install .deb packages But I Got errors as below.

```
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgsl0-dev:i386:
libgsl0-dev:i386 depends on libgsl0ldbl (= 1.15+dfsg-1build1).
dpkg: error processing libgsl0-dev:i386 (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libopenscenegraph-dev:i386:
libopenscenegraph-dev:i386 depends on libopenthreads-dev.
libopenscenegraph-dev:i386 depends on libgl1-mesa-dev | libgl-dev.
libopenscenegraph-dev:i386 depends on libglu-dev.
libopenscenegraph-dev:i386 depends on libopenscenegraph80 (= 3.0.1-2).
dpkg: error processing libopenscenegraph-dev:i386 (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libosgearth-dev:i386:
libosgearth-dev:i386 depends on libopenscenegraph-dev; however:
Package libopenscenegraph-dev:i386 is not configured yet.
libosgearth-dev:i386 depends on libgeos-dev; however:
Package libgeos-dev:i386 is not configured yet.
```

Errors are the same for every package, all dependencies probs. 
I have installed all deb. packages and dependecies in one pc.
So My question is ,  How do copy all same and install on other pc that is not connected to internet.  is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve a dependency issue by installing manually a package with `dpkg -i --force-depends <PathToPackageNameThatBlocks.deb>`.

Because you said that the second machine does NOT have a internet connection you can try out the tool `debmirror` on the first machine. The mirror that is created can then be copied to the second machine and included into your `/etc/apt/sources.list` for `apt-get`.

The description and manual of this tool can be found by typing `man debmirror` in the command line.

Comment: :- will "debmirror" copy all packages and their dependencies from first machine.? so that on other machine I can directly install that after adding in to `/etc/apt/sources.list` ?